# IO. В чем выгода использования буферизации ввода? И как это работает

Tags: java, io

Пытаюсь разобраться с буферизованным вводом-выводом. Объясните чайнику в чем выгода? И главное как она получается. Везде написано что быстрее работает... **Это возможность задать размер пакета?** Или что? **Я видел где как-то задают размер байтового массива, то не задают. Просто калейдоскоп какой-то.**

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как работают эти буферы.

И еще: как задать размер буфера предположим файл реально большой, ну фильм на пример и я его хочу двигать:

```
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(""));
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(""));
// как мне вот тут сказать что писать вот такими byte[32000] для гипотетического примера...
out.write(in.read());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Вкратце**:

Манипуляции с буфером происходят быстрее, чем манипуляции с непосредственным источником данных (например, с жестким диском или сетевым ресурсом).

**Подробнее:**

Как понятно из названия, буферизованный поток – это поток, имеющий буфер.

Предположим, Вы записываете какие-то данные на диск, вызывая метод `write(...)` потока. При использовании буферизованного потока, после вызова `write(...)` данные не пишутся на диск, они сохраняются в буфере потока. На диск данные попадают либо при явном вызове `flush()`, либо при закрытии потока.

В чем выгода? – В том, что **при каждом вызове** `write(...)` Вы **не трогаете диск**, а пишите на него бОльшими блоками данных.

Аналогично, при чтении, считывается бОльший блок данных, чем нужен Вам. При последующем чтении Вы получаете информацию не с диска, а из буфера.

В общем случае выгода заключается в том, что при каждом чтении/записи Вы не трогаете сам непосредственный источник данных, чтение/запись на который **происходит медленнее**, чем чтение/запись из буфера.

**UPD**:

Размер буфера определяется при создании потока с помощью конструкторов:

```
BufferedOutputStream(OutputStream out, int size)
```

и

```
BufferedInputStream(InputStream in, int size)
```

Comment: Я понял спасибо. А как задать размер буфера? у меня на пример такой код: BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(""));
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(""));

            out.write(in.read());

Comment: @Павел, Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: А разве UPD это не для потокового видео?

Comment: @Павел, Причем тут вообще видео, да еще и потоковое? Это размер буфера для потока, безотносительно рода данных, с которыми будет работать поток.

Comment: Ой пардон! Читал UPD а прочитал UDP

Comment: а как расшифровыватся абривеатура?

Comment: @Павел, UPD == Updated.

Comment: А в этой конструкции BufferedOutputStream(OutputStream out, int size); int size это понимать как длинну массива байтов или что-то еще?

Comment: @Павел, Да, [именно так и понимать](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.java#BufferedOutputStream.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.OutputStream%2Cint%29).

Answer (score 3):

Если ввод не буферизовать, а вместо этого читать файлы по байту за раз, получится очень медленно — при каждом чтении где-то внутри будет вызываться системный `read()`, а [системные вызовы в целом медленнее](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2). К тому же, в целом с данными вообще лучше работать большими группами за раз.

Answer (score 3):

Если говорить простым языком, с помощью буферизации программный код в операциях чтения/записи не дергает винчестер для каждого байта, а проводит операции сразу с большим их кол-вом, массивом.